# How do I construct a shell script that searches for any matches from list of regex?

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to write a shell script runs through each regex in a list (results.txt) and searches for any matches in a subdirectory. Is using the find command the right approach in this scenario? I could try python but I don't have much background.

Example of what some of the regex in results.txt look like:

> /underway/(.)*.(GPS|gps)

Here's a piece I've come up with so far

```
for i in results.txt
find -regextype egrep -regex "i"
    if find:
        Print ("Found")
    else:
        print ("not found")
```

Comment: You are mixing python and shell syntax -_-

Comment: Whoops. You're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: `for line in $(cat results.txt); do find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ${line} ; done`

Comment: It seems like you need to learn shell scripting, your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: The duplicate is for `-name` instead of `-regex` but I should hope it's obvious what needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to build regular expressions dynamically from the lines of the file and make only a single call to `find` without using a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

# slurp the file into the variable eres (extended regular expressions)
eres=$(<results.txt)
# replace each newline character with a |
eres=${eres//$'\n'/'|'}
# Now, $eres is in the form of regex1|regex2|…|regexn

find . -regextype egrep -regex "$eres"
```

Comment: The parentheses around each entry are redundant, `|` has very low precedence.

Comment: @tripleee Right. I've overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

For shell command

```
cat result.txt | while read -r line; do
    [[ ${line} ]] && find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "${line}" 
done > > (sort | uniq)
```

---

P.S. This is for Linux. If under Mac, `find` command had to use `-E` instead of `-regextype`.

---

P.S.
`[[ ! -z ${line} ]]` ignores the empty "line".

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Also, remember that a regex can reasonably include whitespace, or asterisks, or asterisks surrounded by whitespace. If `line='.*'`, then `-regex $line` will put a list of dotfiles on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I up-voted.  Let me update my answer. I normally use pipeline actually.  This time, I just try to follow the content of the original question.

Comment: Much better. As a further correctness fix, I'd also use the `-r` argument to `read` so it doesn't munge backslashes. I'd also think about changing from `cat result.txt | while ... done` to `while ... done <result.txt` -- it doesn't matter much in this particular case, but it's a bit faster to start up (no reason to invoke a copy of `/bin/cat`) and can help avoid the problems described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (granted, to avoid them here, you'd also need to change from `| sort | uniq` to `> >(sort | uniq)` or similar, and it's generally not worth the pain).

Comment: BTW, `[[ $line ]]` is maybe a slightly terser way to avoid empty lines :)

Comment: ...and it should be double quotes, not single, in `-regex "$line"`

Comment: Looks good to me as amended.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. It sharps my skills at the same time.